# jQuery Attribute Equals Selector without element

Tags: jquery

How does a jQuery Attribute Equals Selector work without an element to search through?

For example

```
$("[data-meta=state]").val()
```

Comment: it won't do anything if the selector doesn't match any element

Comment: As an aside, can someone explain why I got downvoted on this? Not complaining- just want to know why this isn't a satisfactory question

Comment: i didn't downvote dude

Comment: @mrid I didn't mean you specifically, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all element you have to use the "*" character which means all and after it use the attribute/value pair like the example in this answer

```
 $("*[data-meta=state]").val();
```

Comment: it'll be better if you can add an explanation so as to why this is working ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's not what I was asking. If you don't have the *, does it still search through all elements?

Comment: "If you want to select all element you have to use the "*" character which means all" ، only this character means all without it it will not response